# Target class [Micoleccion\Subscription\PayPalClient] does not exist. LARAVEL

Tags: php, html, laravel, paypal

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con **Laravel 9.X**, y estoy intentando implementar subscripciones con la *API de PayPal*. El problema me aparece cuando llamo a una clase que he creado llamado **PayPalClient**, que se encuentra en la siguiente ruta:

> miAplicacionLaravel/micoleccion/Subscription/PayPalClient.php

En esta clase, he puesto el `namespace` que corresponde, en este caso: `namespace Micoleccion\Subscription;`

También tengo un controlador desde el cual intento acceder a esta clase, de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Micoleccion\Subscription\PayPalClient;

    class PaypalController extends Controller
    {
        private $paypalClient;
    
        public function __construct(PayPalClient $payPalClient)
        {
            $this->paypalClient = $payPalClient;
        }
    
        public function createMicoleccionProduct()
        {
            $product = [
                'name' => 'Suscripción a la herramienta',
                'description' => 'Acceso a todos los beneficios de la plataforma',
                'type' => 'SERVICE',
                'category' => 'SOFTWARE',
            ];
    
            try {
                return $this->paypalClient->createProduct($product);
            } catch (ClientException $exception) {
                dd($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

> Target class [Micoleccion\Subscription\PayPalClient] does not exist.

También he probado a crearlo dentro del constructor directamente, y el error cambia de aspecto pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo, que no encuentra la clase:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $payPalClient = new \Micoleccion\Subscription\PayPalClient;
    $this->paypalClient = $payPalClient;
}
```

> Class "Micoleccion\Subscription\PayPalClient" not found

También he probado a crear un objeto desde el **Tinker**, pero el error sigue diciéndome que no la consigue encontrar, ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: Que paquete estas usando para la implementacion de PayPal?

Comment: @adrigo Estoy haciendo llamadas a la api del paypal, esto lo hago dentro de mi clase PayPalClient, a la cual no consigo acceder

Comment: Osea que estas usando creando todo tu desde cero? Porque no usas algun paquete ya existente? he estado mirando y tenog unos cuantos para proponerte, si quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias @adrigo , pero lo que necesito es poder llamar a mi clase, en la que ya tengo métodos creados para hacer lo que necesito

Comment: No acabo de entender muy bien la finalidad de crear a tu forma algo que ya existe con modulos mantenidos por gente que seguramente entienda mas del tema que tu... ademas de que tendra muchas mas funcionalidades y en cuanto a seguridad seguramente sean mucho mejores... es reinventar la rueda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel por defecto carga sólo las clases que están indicadas en el archivo [`composer.json`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8d3a964edc67125f336f14ccfca31b62623bca65/composer.json#L23) bajo las claves `"autoload": { "psr-4": { ... } }`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

Como el namespace de tu clase `Micoleccion\Subscription` no está especificado en el autoload, Laravel simplemente lo desconoce.

Para resolverlo se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Mover tu namespace para que quede dentro del namespace `App`, que ya está incluído por defecto en el autoload. Quedando por ejemplo así `App\Micoleccion\Subscription` y la estructura de directorios así `miAplicacionLaravel/app/Micoleccion/Subscription/`.
2. Configurar el autoload para que cargue las clases de tu namespace

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Micoleccion\\Subscription\\" : "micoleccion/Subscription/"
    }
},
```

Y correr `composer dump-autoload` para que se vuelvan a cargar las clases junto con las del nuevo namespace.
Nota que namespaces y clases deben cumplir con el standard [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) que es requerido por Laravel.

Comment: He utilizado la segunda opción que me planteas, y ha funcionado a la perfección. Muchas gracias